# C#: Save and load two JPEG images to and from a single file

Tags: c#, stream, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

My Windows Phone application saves an object composed by some textual/numerical information (something like image capture date and so on) and a couple of JPEG image.
For example and simplicity, a single file may be composed by the following data order:

```
from byte 0 to 3 -----> INT NUMBER
from byte 4 to 11 ----> TWO INTs DESCRIBING THE SIZE OF THE NEXT IMAGE
from byte 12 to X ----> FIRST JPEG IMAGE
from byte X+1 to X+7 -> TWO INTs DESCRIBING THE SIZE OF THE NEXT IMAGE
from byte X+8 to Y ---> SECOND JPEG IMAGE
```

I've implemented the saving method this way:

```
public bool SaveDataToMemory(string filename) 
{
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (!appStorage.DirectoryExists(App.USER_FOLDER))
        {
            appStorage.CreateDirectory(App.USER_FOLDER);
        }

        if (appStorage.FileExists(filename))
        {
            appStorage.DeleteFile(filename);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = null;
        using (fs = appStorage.CreateFile(filename))
        {
            int thumbW = (int)this.thumbnail.PixelWidth;
            int thumbH = (int)this.thumbnail.PixelHeight;
            int thumbLength = thumbW * thumbH;

            int imageW = (int)this.imageSize.Width;
            int imageH = (int)this.imageSize.Height;
            int imageLength = imageW * imageH;

            byte[] byteToWrite;
            int bufferCount;

            byteToWrite = BitConverter.GetBytes(DATA_VERSION); // THE FIRST INT NUMBER
            fs.Write(byteToWrite, 0, byteToWrite.Length);

            byteToWrite = BitConverter.GetBytes(thumbW); // THE FIRST COUPLE OF INTs
            fs.Write(byteToWrite, 0, byteToWrite.Length);
            byteToWrite = BitConverter.GetBytes(thumbH);
            fs.Write(byteToWrite, 0, byteToWrite.Length);

            this.thumbnail.SaveJpeg(fs, thumbW, thumbH, 0, 75); // THE FIRST IMAGE (WriteableBitmap)


            byteToWrite = BitConverter.GetBytes(imageW); // THE SECOND COUPLE OF INTs
            fs.Write(byteToWrite, 0, byteToWrite.Length);
            byteToWrite = BitConverter.GetBytes(imageH);
            fs.Write(byteToWrite, 0, byteToWrite.Length);

            this.image.SaveJpeg(fs, imageW, imageH, 0, 92); // THE SECOND IMAGE
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method should work, at least there are no exception thrown.
Now the problem is when I try to load them back. 
I access the stream following the data order described before, I can retrieve and view the first image ("thumbnail") with `WriteableBitmap.LoadJpeg`, but when I continue in order to retrive the next integers they appear to be 0 and the second image fails to load with an exception.

```
public bool LoadDataFromMemory(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = null;

        if (!appStorage.FileExists(filename)) return false;

        using (fs = appStorage.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fs == null) return false;

            byte[] dataVersionBuf = new byte[sizeof(Int32)]; // FIRST INTEGER
            fs.Read(dataVersionBuf, 0, dataVersionBuf.Length);
            int dataVersion = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataVersionBuf, 0);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data version:" + dataVersion);

            byte[] thumbSizeBuf = new byte[8];
            fs.Read(thumbSizeBuf, 0, thumbSizeBuf.Length); // SIZE OF THE NEXT IMAGE

            int thumbW = BitConverter.ToInt32(thumbSizeBuf, 0);
            int thumbH = BitConverter.ToInt32(thumbSizeBuf, 4);

            this.thumbnail = new WriteableBitmap(thumbW, thumbH);
            this.thumbnail.LoadJpeg(fs); // FIRST IMAGE

            // (this prints the correct information)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loaded thumbnail " + this.thumbnail.PixelWidth + "x" + this.thumbnail.PixelHeight); 

            byte[] leftSizeBuf = new byte[sizeof(Int32) * 2];
            fs.Read(leftSizeBuf, 0, leftSizeBuf.Length); // <<--- PROBLEMS READING HERE!

            int imageW = BitConverter.ToInt32(leftSizeBuf, 0);
            int imageH = BitConverter.ToInt32(leftSizeBuf, 4);
            // imageW and imageH are equal to 0!!!!

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loading left " + imageW + "x" + imageH);

            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(imageW, imageH);
            wb.LoadJpeg(fs); // <--- EXCEPTION HERE!

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The thrown exception is a `System.ArgumentException: incorrect parameter`.
Am I implementing the wrong method to store two images in the same stream/file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! Starting from Xenolightning's answer, first of all I save the JPEG data into a separate `MemoryStream`, this way I can get its final length with `MemoryStream.Length`. 
I write the length into the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` as a simple integer and after that I write the whole contents from the previous MemoryStream with `MemoryStream.WriteTo().`

```
// preparing thumbnail stream & length
ms = new MemoryStream();
this.thumbnail.SaveJpeg(ms, thumbW, thumbH, 0, 80);
thumbLength = (int)ms.Length;

// THUMB FILESIZE
byteToWrite = BitConverter.GetBytes(thumbLength);
fs.Write(byteToWrite, 0, byteToWrite.Length);

// THUMB DATA
ms.WriteTo(fs);
```

When loading back, I first read the file size data block, then the proper amount of data with `fs.Read()` is transferred to a MemoryStream, then it's converted to a bitmap object.

```
// THUMB FILESIZE
byteToRead = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
fs.Read(byteToRead, 0, byteToRead.Length);
int thumbSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteToRead, 0);

// GET RAW DATA
jpegData = new byte[thumbSize];
fs.Read(jpegData, 0, thumbSize);

// CREATE IMAGE OBJECT
ms = new MemoryStream(jpegData);
this.thumbnail = new WriteableBitmap(thumbW, thumbH);
this.thumbnail.LoadJpeg(ms);
```

Comment: Good stuff, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to unexpected behaviour in the `WriteableBitmap.LoadJpeg` Method. It could over-run your stream, which may then cause the rest of your stream to be in an unpredictable position. I would suggest updating your format to add the FileSize of the jpeg (in bytes), and pull a `MemoryStream` out of your `FileStream` to pass to `WriteableBitmap.LoadJpeg`.

Something along the lines of: (there may be a compilation issue, I'm not at a dev machine to check)

```
//...
byte[] jpegSizeBytes = new byte[sizeof(Int32)]; // GET THE JPEG SIZE
fs.Read(jpegSizeBytes , 0, jpegSizeBytes.Length);
int jpegSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(jpegSizeBytes , 0);

byte[] jpegData = new byte[jpegSize];
fs.Read(jpegData, 0, jpegSize);

using(var ms = new MemoryStream(jpegData))
{
    this.thumbnail = new WriteableBitmap(thumbW, thumbH);
    this.thumbnail.LoadJpeg(ms); // FIRST IMAGE
}
//...
```

Use the same technique as above for loading  the second image too.

Comment: I understand, but... how can I store and retrieve the JPEG SIZE data field? It's a value to be added before calling this.thumbnail.SaveJpeg(), right? But how can I know the actual value before calling that method?

Comment: And, by the way, how could LoadJpeg() over-run the stream by itself? If true, that's a huge C# bug!

Comment: When using `LoadJpeg()` there is no parameter for the number of bytes to read. So that method could theoretically read until it found an error (which could be one byte after the jpeg data), this would cause the stream to be offset. Without looking at the source, we aren't able to deduce the problem. It's much safer to pass the `MemoryStream` because 'we' don't care about its position